# Async redirect testing with Capybara and Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

When I test for content on a page which is loaded async I can test it like this:

```
  assert page.should have_content(content)
```

This works because it keeps checking for the content untill it gets on the page (or time out).

How do you do this with redirecting? I redirect from /index.html#login to /index.html#main
This is how I do it now, but that does not work: `page.current_url.include?(uri)`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I guess this should get you the right URL:

`current_url = evaluate_script(window.location.href)`

Instead of `href` you could also work with `hash` and `pathname`